# SO password recovery, here's your password, just kidding

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, security

I tried SO password recovery,

you enter your email and a captcha after you get an e-mail:

```
here's your password : aaa3437

just kidding, 

go to this link ....
```

is it considered a bad idea to generate a random password and send it to the e-mail ?

for example:

```
1: send an email with a password reset link
2: click on the link, pass reset occurs, send email with new password
```

Comment: Probably, maybe they want all password changes done on their website. ??

Comment: Man, that's hilarious.  I approve.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We don't ever send passwords in emails, that's a big no-no.  We send single-use recovery links, like the one that e-mail contains.

Even temporary passwords don't make any sense.  You don't actually want someone to *use* those, you want them to immediately reset them; so making someone copy/paste one into a form is just pointless busy work.

As [Michael](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/145982/michael-mrozek) points out, it's a joking "take that" at the depressing number of sites that get this wrong.

It's also worth noting that the "joke passwords" sent in those emails are not sufficiently complex to be used with our OpenID provider.  The code to generate them can be [found here](http://code.google.com/p/stackid/source/browse/OpenIdProvider/Views/Templates/ResetPassword.cshtml#13); it uses a list of common passwords, minus some of the more risque ones.

Comment: about the single-use recovery link, the code in this link is used until the password is changed or you just keep creating new single use codes for each request ( the user might do several posts e.g. passwords don't match)

Comment: btw, if you just click 'Change Password' on the recovery form without filling anything you get the message "Password cannot match your account name, in whole or in part."

Answer (score 15):

I imagine the joke is "here's your current password"; passwords should be stored in a way that makes recovering the original impossible, so claiming to have the current password is making fun of all the sites that [fail at password storage](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html). As for issuing you a random password, most people are probably going to change it immediately anyway, so they might as well cut out that step and just give you a link directly to a page that lets you set a new password

Comment: As seen on `<del>` TV `</del><ins>` [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/questions/293217/our-security-auditor-is-an-idiot-how-do-i-give-him-the-information-he-wants) `</ins>`

Answer (score 1):

That's no longer the case.

These days they send email to the given address, with the following text:

> We received an account recovery request on Meta Stack Exchange for [email here]
> If you initiated this request, reset your password here.

No more joking around.